# ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'community.general.timezone'

Tags: ansible

I have this error

> ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'community.general.timezone'

OS is RedHat 8; Ansible version 2.9.27

So, I installed the missing collection via `ansible-galaxy`, but I am still getting the same error.
How can I make Ansible recognise the installed collection?

```bash
# ansible-galaxy collection install community.general
Process install dependency map
Starting collection install process
Installing 'community.general:6.1.0' to '/root/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/community/general'
```

Comment: Make sure that you have set collections_paths in ansible.cfg file to the path where your collection is downloaded

Answer (score 2):

You should upgrade Ansible.

Ansible 2.9 [reached end of life 2022-05-23](https://groups.google.com/g/ansible-announce/c/kegIH5_okmg/m/MNxt0oM1AwAJ) and lacks some important collection features which required workarounds on the collection side. The `community.general` collection [removed those workarounds](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/pull/4548) when it stopped supporting Ansible 2.9 in v5.0.0.